SSR Based Chi2 Test Significant but F Test Not Significant in Granger Causality Analysis - How to Report in Results?
I'm using Python's statsmodels library to perform a Granger causality test between two variables. My results show a significant p-value for the SSR based Chi2 test, but the SSR based F test p-value is not significant. I'm wondering how to interpret and report these results in my paper. Specifically, can I still conclude that there is Granger causality between the variables?
Here are some details of the analysis:
ADF Test for independent_var: p-value = 2.4785e-05
ADF Test for dependent_var: p-value = 0.0368
Model:                         VAR
Method:                        OLS
...
No. of Equations:         2
Results for equation independent_var:
    L1.independent_var        coef=-0.5826, p=0.335
    L2.dependent_var          coef=0.0106, p=0.066
Results for equation dependent_var:
    L2.independent_var       coef=-81.4693, p=0.016
    L2.dependent_var          coef=-0.7336, p=0.038

Granger Causality Test Results:
number of lags (no zero) 1
ssr based F test:         F=0.5203  , p=0.4978
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=0.7805  , p=0.3770
number of lags (no zero) 2
ssr based F test:         F=3.9944  , p=0.1426
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=21.3037 , p=0.0000

Given this scenario, is it appropriate to report the significant Chi2 test as evidence of Granger causality, despite the non-significant F test? How should I interpret these mixed results when writing up the findings?

how long is your time series? Can you increase the number of lags? With a short time series, small degrees of freedom, the F distribution is generally more accurate. But there might be not enough information in the data to give a conclusive answer. (The dependent variable has a strong correlation with lags of the independent variable, strong feedback, so it might be difficult to get reliable estimates for granger causality.)
